# Sending Data from iOS to java socket server

Tags: java, objective-c

Hi I have the next issue, why when I send data like this

```
uint8_t buffer[11] = "I send this";

NSInteger nwritten = [outputStream write:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];

if (-1 == nwritten) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing to stream %@: %@", outputStream, [outputStream streamError]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Wrote %i bytes to stream %@.", nwritten, outputStream);
}
```

in the other side in the java socket server

```
connection = new Socket(Constants.HOST, Constants.CHAT_LISTENER_PORT);
_in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
String data = _in.readUTF();
```

But nothing appear like as if it had not sent anything.

I read to much and I found the problem is from platforms because java byte works with big-endians and iOS with little-endians but I don't found information about how do to this.

**uint8_t buffer[11] = "I send this"; to big-Endians format**

Please heellppp, thanks.

Sorry my English is very but there is nothing in spanish :/ thaks.

Comment: Your English is fine. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the server side in the next Line in java code:

```
DataInputStream.readUTF();
```

this .readUTF() expect a UTF java native type what is not the same with objective-c type, and the solution was send the string codifying in UTF native java like this.

```
NSString *msg = @"initChat_";
NSString *messageToSend  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", msg];
NSData *data = [self convertToJavaUTF8:messageToSend];

int dataLenght = [data length];

int num = [outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)[data bytes] maxLength:dataLenght];


if (-1 == num) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing to stream %@: %@", outputStream, [outputStream streamError]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Wrote %i bytes to stream %@.", num, outputStream);
}
```

**And the Magic come from:**

```
- (NSData*) convertToJavaUTF8 : (NSString*) str {
NSUInteger len = [str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
Byte buffer[2];    
buffer[0] = (0xff & (len >> 8));
buffer[1] = (0xff & len);
NSMutableData *outData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:2];
[outData appendBytes:buffer length:2];        
[outData appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
return outData;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **swift4** version of the answer.

```
extension String {
    func javaUTF8() -> Data? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        let length = self.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)
        var buffer = [UInt8]()
        buffer.append(UInt8(0xff & (length >> 8)))
        buffer.append(UInt8(0xff & length))
        var outdata = Data()
        outdata.append(buffer, count: buffer.count)
        outdata.append(data)
        return outdata
    }
}
```

you can use it, as below.

```
let data = "hello word".javaUTF8()
```

Answer (score 0):

readUTF expects a specific format, you need to send the length as a big-endian 16-bit unsigned short, followed by the text UTF encoded.  I suspect its taking the first bytes as the length which works out to a large number so it is waiting for this many characters to be read.

UTF-8 is not big endian or little endian, so this is not a problem for you. If you are sending 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit data values, then you could have a problem with endianness.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796633/sending-data-from-ios-to-java-socket-server-and-recognizes-the-message)

Comment: You need to start with a simple string and work you way up.  Try writing a 1 byte string and make sure it is decoded correctly.  Then you can try a string with a character which needs to be encoded. e.g. € You are doing something incorrect but I don't know objectve-c

Answer (score 0):

At your request string end add `\n`

For example `uint8_t buffer[] = "I send this\n"`,it may work.