# Sending Data from iOS to java socket server and recognizes the message

Tags: java, ios

I don't understand this, I do this code in my app and in the server side don't recognized well the message why?

```
NSString *init = @"?II#$%_0";
NSData *myData = [init dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
uint8_t *readBytes = (uint8_t *)[myData bytes];
int size = [myData length]; 
int myInteger = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(size);
NSInteger nwritten = [outputStream write:readBytes maxLength:myInteger];
```

And in the other side in the remote server recognizes the message but not well like this.

`0I0I0#0$0%0_0O0000000000000000#0000000000000000`

this have the I I # $ _ 0 from the string message what I'm sending but with 000000 and this 000 is not cero is a square but I did not know how to write this character.

and next the error

`java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 27
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:639)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)`

I don't understand wh?? please heelp sorry for my english is very bad. :/

Comment: Can you show the Java code that's reading it? The problem could easily be that Java is expecting UTF-8, UCS-2 or some other encoding.

Comment: No men, I don't think so, because in the other side in the server wait for data with the next piece of code `DataInputStream.readUTF()` and the message appear in the server but with other characters like 000000000 is not zeros there are squares.                                    Any idea please somebody help!!!! sorry for my English :/

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for my Englis is very bad. :/
Finally I found the solution to the headache hahahaha, yeaaa :)

In the side of the server in the next Line in java code:

```
DataInputStream.readUTF();
```

this .readUTF() expect a UTF java native type what is not the same with objective-c type, and the solution was send the string codifying in UTF native java like this.

```
NSString *msg = @"initChat_";
NSString *messageToSend  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", msg];
NSData *data = [self convertToJavaUTF8:messageToSend];

int dataLenght = [data length];

int num = [outputStream write:(const uint8_t *)[data bytes] maxLength:dataLenght];


if (-1 == num) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing to stream %@: %@", outputStream, [outputStream streamError]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Wrote %i bytes to stream %@.", num, outputStream);
}
```

**And the Magic come from:**

```
- (NSData*) convertToJavaUTF8 : (NSString*) str {
NSUInteger len = [str lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
Byte buffer[2];    
buffer[0] = (0xff & (len >> 8));
buffer[1] = (0xff & len);
NSMutableData *outData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:2];
[outData appendBytes:buffer length:2];        
[outData appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
return outData;}
```

Cheers.....

Answer (score 2):

`DataInputStream.readUTF()` reads data that has been encoded in the special prefixed format produced by, and described in the Javadoc for, `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`. It's not a generic method for reading UTF strings. Use a `BufferedReader` with an appropriate charset.

Comment: This is the problem I can't move or modify the code in the server side, because this works well with androide and bb, I need to send the porperly data for `DataInputStream.readUTF()` can reed well the message, any idea please somebody help!!!! sorry my english is very bad :/.

Comment: @user1276068 So you need to adhere to exactly what it specifies under `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`. Clearly you aren't.