# Python and Java Socket Server differences - Java lags responding to iOS app, but both respond to telnet

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sockets

Weird issue here - 
I have identical what should be identical Python and Java servers, which I'm trying access with an iOS app.  Everything works great with the Python server.  The Python server and the Java server behave identically when accessed via telnet.  Only the Java terminal reacts to the communication after I close the iOS app!  It seems like it only processes after the process is shut down.  Then everything shows up in terminal belatedly.

Are there encoding differences or something?  It just seems strange that there's a delay and some functionality.  I've tried implementing the suggested recoding method from here but no dice.
[Sending Data from iOS to java socket server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752580/sending-data-from-ios-to-java-socket-server)

Any suggestions?  Thanks much.  Pretty stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out there just needs to be a \n at the end of the Obj-C transmissions to get the Buffered Reader's readLine method to work.  Documentation ftw.

Comment: IOW your a python and Java servers weren't identical at all.